# Dynamic programming solution to the shortest distance two-finger typing problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to educate myself better about **dynamic programming**, and hoping to do so by attempting to solve the following problem (for reference  [here's a solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-distance-to-type-a-word-using-two-fingers/) to it).

> You have a keyboard layout as shown above in the XY plane, where each English uppercase letter is located at some coordinate, for example, the letter A is located at coordinate (0,0), the letter B is located at coordinate (0,1), the letter P is located at coordinate (2,3) and the letter Z is located at coordinate (4,1).
>
> [image]
>
> Given the string word, return the minimum total distance to type such string using only two fingers. The distance between coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is |x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|.
>
> Note that the initial positions of your two fingers are considered free so don't count towards your total distance, also your two fingers do not have to start at the first letter or the first two letters.

For example for the input word `"HAPPY"` we would have:

```
Output: 6
Explanation: 
Using two fingers, one optimal way to type "HAPPY" is:
Finger 1 on letter 'H' -> cost = 0
Finger 1 on letter 'A' -> cost = Distance from letter 'H' to letter 'A' = 2
Finger 2 on letter 'P' -> cost = 0
Finger 2 on letter 'P' -> cost = Distance from letter 'P' to letter 'P' = 0
Finger 1 on letter 'Y' -> cost = Distance from letter 'A' to letter 'Y' = 4
Total distance = 6
```

From what I read online there are 1D, 2D and 3D (in terms of space) dynamic programming solutions to the above problem. I have found 1D and 2D solutions online to this problem, but I find them too difficult to follow, so I'm hoping to start with the 3D one and gradually understand more efficient ones.

What's a 3D DP formulation to this problem? Does this problem have a name in particular?

I understand the recursive nature of the problem, but I'm struggling to formulate a **simple** bottom-up solution  (e.g. in 3D).

Comment: Interesting problem. I find artificial intelligence algorithms very likely to solve it, but maybe you are looking for a brute force algorithm, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly simple 3-D dynamic programming approach is the following:

```
def dist(a,b): # gets distance between chars a and b
    y1,x1 = a/6,a%6
    y2,x2 = b/6,b%6
    return abs(y1-y2)+abs(x1-x2)

def solve(s):
    N = len(s)
    dp = [[[float('inf') for x in range(26)] for x in range(26)] for x in range(N+1)]
    dp[0] = [[0 for x in range(26)] for x in range(26)]
    for i in range(N):
         cur = ord(s[i])-ord('A')
         for j in range(26):
              for k in range(26):
                   dp[i+1][j][cur] = min(dp[i+1][j][cur], dp[i][j][k] + dist(k,cur)) # move right finger
                   dp[i+1][cur][k] = min(dp[i+1][cur][k], dp[i][j][k] + dist(j,cur)) # move left finger
    res = float('inf')
    for i in dp[N]:
         res = min(res,min(i))
    return res
```

In the `solve` function, we declare a dynamic programming table `dp[N+1][26][26]`, and let's store at cell `dp[i][j][k]` the minimum distance required to type all characters in the string *up to but not including* the i'th character, with the left finger finishing on the j'th key and the right finger on the k'th key.

Our base case is at `i = 0`, we know it takes `0` total distance to have our fingers start anywhere, so the first row is initialized entirely with `0`s. Then, the transition is from all possible configurations of the two fingers to either moving the left finger or the right finger to the new key. If you're currently at state `dp[i][j][k]`, after pressing the i'th key (let's call it `cur`), if we press this new key with our left finger, the updated state is `dp[i+1][cur][k]`, since the left finger moved from j to `cur`. Similarly, if we press it with our right finger, the updated state is `dp[i+1][j][cur]`.

Our final answer is found somewhere in the `N+1`'th row, where `N` is the length of the string. We simply take the minimum of all combinations of left and right fingers in this row.

EDIT:
Here's the 2-D solution I described in the comments:

```
def solve(s):
    N = len(s)
    dp = [[float('inf') for x in range(26)]for x in range(N)]
    dp[0] = [0 for x in range(26)]
    for i in range(1,N):
        cur = ord(s[i])-ord('A')
        lst = ord(s[i-1])-ord('A')
        for j in range(26): # one finger currently on s[i-1], other finger on j
             dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], dp[i-1][j] + dist(lst,cur)) # move first finger, so second finger remains on j
             dp[i][lst] = min(dp[i][lst], dp[i-1][j] + dist(j,cur))   # move second finger, so second finger becomes the new "first finger"
                                                                                # and now the old "first finger" becomes the new "second finger"
    res = min(dp[N-1])
    return res
```

Comment: This is great - Thanks! when you said _"the **proceeding** state is `dp[i+1][cur][k]`"_ I presume you meant the _updated_ state, right? Also, do you mind elaborating on _why_ you do the `min` operation? From reading the code I get the impression that the `min` operation always returns its second argument, since the first argument is always `inf` by the time we hit that statement (i.e. we only read and write each location of the 3D array once), or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I do mean updated, bad choice of words on my part. I use the min operation there because there can be several different ways to reach a state: for example, with the next character `B` I can reach the state [left,right] = [A,B] from several states, for instance [A,C] or [A,D] or [B,B], etc, and I just want to pick the optimal choice of all of these.

Comment: Nice! Thanks aeternalis1. And if you don't mind, do you know what's the intuition behind e.g. the 2D DP solution?

Comment: My above solution can be converted to 2D space by removing the `[i]` dimension from the table and only keeping track of the current and previous states, but the other 2D solution I've seen leverages the fact that if you're about to type the `i+1`'th character, you know for sure that one of your fingers is currently on the `i`'th character, so you only need to keep track of the other finger. Then you only require `dp[N+1][26]`, and if you optimize memory some more you can reduce it to `dp[26]`.

Comment: Thanks! And one more QQ, in the 3D solution, when you say `# move [right/left] finger`, it's more like `# We would press the cur letter with [right/left] finger by moving it from THIS letter instead of the previously best seen letter` right? and that of course applies only IF that corresponding `min` operation returns the 2nd argument (otherwise we are not updating FROM what letter it's best to move that finger), correct? (mostly asking for pedagogical reasons, since this is a great DP problem)

Comment: Yeah so in the case of the right finger it's `press letter "cur" by moving it from letter "k"` and for the left finger it's by moving it from letter `j`. And yes, such an operation only matters if it obtains a result more optimal than previously found results (i.e. it's minimal in the corresponding `min` operation).